# How to display Flask image to HTML directly without saving?

Tags: python, flask

flask code:

```
from base64 import b64encode
def abc()
    encoded = b64encode(img_data)
    mime = "image/jpeg"
    uri = "data:%s;base64,%s" % (mime, encoded)

    return render_template('/result.html',uri=uri)
```

html code:

```
<img src="{{ uri }}">
```

I tried this, but the image is not getting displayed. Any idea how? I have image in a numpy array.

Comment: There is no Flask code in your question

Comment: Edited, sorry  i thought, it was obvious

Comment: try this: `return render_template('/result.html', uri=uri)`

Comment: I am doing exactly that

Comment: @johndoe, yeah now you do, but before it was `'=uri=uri`

Comment: Yeah, it was just in the question. Nvm I solved it now

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

```
file_object = io.BytesIO()
img= Image.fromarray(originalimg.astype('uint8'))
img.save(file_object, 'PNG')
base64img = "data:image/png;base64,"+b64encode(file_object.getvalue()).decode('ascii')
```

HTML:

```
<img src="{{base64img}}"      >
```

Answer (score 2):

this is just the complementary solution for the above solution, I was searching for this for like 12 hours, thanks @john_doe, here is my solution combined with the above solution I hope it also helps someone:

```
def upload_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file'].read()
        #    print(f)
        npimg = np.fromstring(f,np.uint8)
        img = cv2.imdecode(npimg,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        img = Image.fromarray(img.astype("uint8"))
        rawBytes = io.BytesIO()
        img.save(rawBytes, "JPEG")
        rawBytes.seek(0)
        img_base64 = base64.b64encode(rawBytes.getvalue()).decode('ascii')
        mime = "image/jpeg"
        uri = "data:%s;base64,%s"%(mime, img_base64)
        return render_template("./template/output.html",image=uri)
```